# Word Usage: ほがらかな vs 人懐っこい

Tags: word-choice, nuances, word-usage

I am doing some JLPT prep, and I'm struggling with the differences between ほがらかな and 人懐っこい。

> 私は、誰にでも抱っこされる（　）赤ちゃんだったらしい。
>
> **A**「ほがらかな」 **B**「人懐っこい」

The given correct answer is 人懐っこい which I can understand as *a sociable/friendly baby anyone can hold*.

But I don't see how ほがらかな is a bad choice.  *A cheerful/happy baby anyone can hold* seems fine to me...

Any hints?

Comment: JLPT questions tend to look for the *best fitting* or *most appropriate* answer.

Comment: @JansthcirlU But ほがらかな赤ちゃん sounds rather unnatural to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps even without those options, many native speakers can instantly give 人懐っこい or 人見知り(を)しない as the most natural expression which fits in that blank. 人懐っこい is such a common adjective to describe a friendly baby who smiles instead of crying when held by a stranger. 人懐っこい is also commonly used to describe a friendly animal. This is a rather simple vocabulary question, so you have to memorize it.

ほがらか doesn't match the definition in that sentence, and it's usually not used to describe a baby whose personality is not formed yet. I feel someone who is ほがらか is usually at least three years old. We don't use ほがらか to describe an animal, either.